# Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to display only a subset of the data for jitterplot layer.

Here is some psuedocode that will demonstrate what I am attempting, with the jitterplot being a subset of the data used.

```
data <- data
data2 <- data[x > 500, ]

ggplot(data, aes(factor(col1), data[, col2] )) + 
stat_sum("median_hilow",conf.int=0.50, linetype='solid') + 
geom_jitter(data = data2, aes(color=col1, size=col2))
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data

Comment: Have you tried the `subset` function?

Comment: The error I receive whether using subset within the layer or outside is: Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data

Comment: Hmm, are col1 and col2 separate variables, or are you getting them from the data table?

Comment: They are columns in both 'data' and 'data2', where data2 is just a subset of data using data[x > 300, ]

Comment: without providing a reproducible example it's hard to say for sure.  What is `x`?  If `x` isn't in your global environment, `data2` will have no rows

Comment: I'll see about putting together a reproducible. There are definitely rows in data2, but few than in data. They have the same exact columns.

Comment: Try putting `col2` in your global `aes` in `ggplot` rather than `data[,col2]`.

Comment: aosmith, doing this fixed all the errors.